# How to remove the displaying the selected value?

Tags: html

The select value seems to be displayed above the dropdown list. How do i get rid of it?

```html
<div class="col-md-3" align="center" style="padding: 1px;">
    <select id="gender">
        <option value="Gender" selected="" disabled="">Gender</option>
        <option value="Male">Male</option>
        <option value="Female">Female</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

[screenshot of the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BNds3.jpg)

Comment: You need to post a [mcve] in your question. What you have so far is insufficient

Comment: Code is definitely incomplete. Best guess is  you have a binding somewhere on that select that is filling in a label.

Comment: Agree, code which is present in question seems to work fine, there might be some other code which is actually adding a label.

Comment: while inspecting it online, i found this:
<div class="selector" style="width: 66px;">
<span style="width: 66px; user-select: none;">Male</span>
<select class="hide-value">
      <option value="Gender" selected="" disabled="">Gender</option>
      <option value="Male">Male</option>
      <option value="Female">Female</option>
 </select>
</div>